# What is the quota limit of invitations for a google classroom domain acount?

Tags: google-api, quota, google-classroom

i will appriciate any help with my problem, I created a script that basically takes a students list and starts to send invitations to different courses, at some point i am getting this error ***"Error: @UserInvitationQuotaExhausted The user does not have enough quota to invite users to this course.***"
I am using a domain account not a personal account, i have read that the invitations quota for personal accounts is 100 per day, but i can not find any information about domain accounts. **Is there any form to increase the quota of invitations for my domain account?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the [Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/classroom/limits)
[image]
To view or change usage limits for your project, or to request an increase to your quota, do the following:

1. If you don't already have a [billing account](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6288653) for your project, then create one.
2. Visit the Enabled APIs page of the API library in the API Console, and select an API from the list.
3. To view and change quota-related settings, select Quotas. To view usage statistics, select Usage

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i don't have trouble with the processing quota, the problem is with the quota of invitations to a course, according with the documentation, a domain account should not having this restriccion but i am having it, so i think maybe something is wrong with my account configuration

Answer (score 1):

This also seems relevant.

| Activity or feature | Google Workspace or school account | Personal Google Account |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Teachers per class | 20 | 20 |
| Class members (teachers and students) | 1,000 | 250 |
| Classes you can join | 1,000 | 100 maximum, 30 per day |
| Classes you can create | No limit | 30 per day |
| Class-member invitations you can send | 500 per day, per teacher | 100 per day, per teacher |
| Guardians per student | 20 | Feature not available |
| Email address visibility | No limit | Feature not available |
| Topics per class | 200 | 200 |
| Classes you can select to simultaneously post an assignment, material, question, or announcement | 20 | 20 |

Taken from https://support.google.com/edu/classroom/answer/7300976?hl=en (2022-04-14)